# Different methods to calculate standard deviation

Tags: standard-deviation, quality-control

I am doing a study using Statistical Process Control and have to calculate the standard deviation. I am aware of a number of ways to do this.

The first method is using the sum of squares (classic method).

The second method is using the sum of squares but the denominator is replaced by n-1.

The third method is using the Range average and a control chart constant d2 such as :

Standard deviation(sigma) = Average Range / d2.

The value of d2 from the control chart tables is 2.326.

Why would someone use the third method as opposed to the 1st or second method?

Can you point me to any text sources that explain this?

Comment: The third option is not standard deviation, just a measure of deviation. It is quick to calculate in a process engineering setting and makes no assumptions about the normality or otherwise of the underlying measurements.

Comment: I don't think normality is needed to justify the use of (bessel corrected) plug in estimator

Comment: @AndrewZhang Agreed, Bessel's correction can be applied somewhat more generally than under an assumption of normality. However, for many distributions including the normal distribution it turns out to be biased anyway. See this [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unbiased_estimation_of_standard_deviation).